# alternative solution for while loop in sql

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

How can I write following code without using while loop?? Is there any alternative way to avoid while loop in this case??

```
SELECT @count = COUNT(*) from CommonTables

While(@count > 0) 
BEGIN
select top 1 @Sname = Schema_name,@Tname = Name from CommonTables


SET @sql = ''
SET @sql = 'insert into #Temp1 select '''+@Sname+''','''+@Tname+''',column_name,data_type,character_maximum_length FROM '+@DB1+'.information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = '''+@Tname+''' and TABLE_SCHEMA = '''+@Sname+''''

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL

SET @sql = ''
SET @sql = 'insert into #Temp2 select '''+@Sname+''','''+@Tname+''',column_name,data_type,character_maximum_length FROM '+@DB2+'.information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = '''+@Tname+''' and TABLE_SCHEMA = '''+@Sname+''''

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL

DELETE from CommonTables where Name = @Tname and Schema_name = @Sname

SELECT @count = COUNT(*) from CommonTables

END
```

Here CommonTables contain list of tables which are common in 2 databases (DB1 and DB2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't need loop at all.

```
select  @sql    = isnull(@sql, '')
        + N'INSERT INTO #Temp1 '
        + N'SELECT table_schema, table_name,column_name,data_type,character_maximum_length '
        + N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DB1) + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS '
        + N'WHERE table_name = ''' + Name + ''' and TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + Schema_name + ''';' + char(13)
from    CommonTables

print   @sql
exec    sp_executesql @sql
```

if you want don't need 2 separate sp_execute statement for 2 DB. You can combine into one single sp_execute

and here is the query

```
select  @sql    = isnull(@sql, '')
        + N'insert into ' + db.temptbl + ' '
        + N'SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH '
        + N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(db.dbname) + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS '
        + N'WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' + Name + ''' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + Schema_name + ''';' + char(13)
from    CommonTables
        cross join
        (
            select  temptbl = '#Temp1', dbname = 'DB1'  union all
            select  temptbl = '#Temp2', dbname = 'DB2'
        ) db

print   @sql
exec    sp_executesql @sql
```